# How to add labels to a bar chart by numbering. (Making histogram from a list using turtle in python 3.7+)

Tags: python-3.7, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a histogram where there is an entered list with integers from 1-10 repeated x number of times. So, if there are three 6's in the list, the height of the bar should be 60 because 20*3=60.

I am trying to add a label to my bar graph / histogram by labeling with numbers in order, but I am not sure how to do so. Refer to the image below to see what the numbers should look like.

```
def draw_histogram(t,dataList):
    '''draw_histogram(t,dataList) -> None
    uses turtle t to draw a histogram of dataList
    dataList must contain integers from 0-10'''

    t = 0
    while t != 11:

        if dataList.count(t) == 0:
            height = 0
        elif dataList.count(t) == 1:
            height = 20
        elif dataList.count(t) == 2:
            height = 40     
        elif dataList.count(t) == 3:
            height = 60
        elif dataList.count(t) == 4:
            height = 80
        elif dataList.count(t) == 5:
            height = 100
        elif dataList.count(t) == 6:
            height = 120   
        elif dataList.count(t) == 7:
            height = 140
        elif dataList.count(t) == 8:
            height = 160
        elif dataList.count(t) == 9:
            height = 180    
        elif dataList.count(t) == 10:
            height = 200

        bob.forward(height)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(20)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(height)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(20)
        bob.left(180)
        bob.penup()
        bob.forward(35)
        bob.left(90)
        bob.pendown()

        t += 1
    return height

# test suite
import turtle
turtle.setup(600,300) # Change the width of the drawing to 600px and the height to 300px.

wn = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
dataList = [6,8,0,7,7,9,2,9,10,4,8,7,6,9,1,4,6,7,5,7,2,10,4,5,5,6,8]

# move bob back a little bit so he has room
bob.penup()
bob.back(200)
bob.pendown()
bob.left(90)

# draw the histogram
draw_histogram(bob,dataList)
wn.mainloop()
```

[Click here for what the finished product should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92LuX.png)

Comment: Can you make a smaller example? Does the error still occur if the integers are from 0 to 2? And if the list is half as long?
Also you only define `height` inside a function. If you want to use it outside, you need to return it.

Comment: So I returned height in my function, but it still says that 'height' is undefined.

Comment: you need to move the turtle within the loop within the function, i posted an answer that should work in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are trying to do?

```py
def draw_histogram(t,dataList):
    '''draw_histogram(t,dataList) -> None
    uses turtle t to draw a histogram of dataList
    dataList must contain integers from 0-10'''

    t = 0
    while t != 11:

        if dataList.count(t) == 0:
            height = 0
        elif dataList.count(t) == 1:
            height = 20
        elif dataList.count(t) == 2:
            height = 40     
        elif dataList.count(t) == 3:
            height = 60
        elif dataList.count(t) == 4:
            height = 80
        elif dataList.count(t) == 5:
            height = 100
        elif dataList.count(t) == 6:
            height = 120   
        elif dataList.count(t) == 7:
            height = 140
        elif dataList.count(t) == 8:
            height = 160
        elif dataList.count(t) == 9:
            height = 180    
        elif dataList.count(t) == 10:
            height = 200
        bob.right(90)
        style = ('Courier', 7, 'italic')
        bob.pu()
        bob.forward(7)
        bob.pd()
        bob.write(str(t), font=style, align='center')
        bob.pu()
        bob.back(7)
        bob.pd()
        bob.left(90)
        bob.forward(height)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(20)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(height)
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(20)
        bob.left(180)
        bob.penup()
        bob.forward(35)
        bob.left(90)
        bob.pendown()

        t += 1
    return height

# test suite
import turtle
turtle.setup(600,300) # Change the width of the drawing to 600px and the height to 300px.

wn = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()
dataList = [6,8,0,7,7,9,2,9,10,4,8,7,6,9,1,4,6,7,5,7,2,10,4,5,5,6,8]

# move bob back a little bit so he has room
bob.penup()
bob.back(200)
bob.pendown()
bob.left(90)

# draw the histogram
draw_histogram(bob,dataList)
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I wanted (thanks!). But, the only thing is that I want a space in-between each bar and for each bar to be a complete rectangle (except the one that is just a line). I also need to label them by numbers. I have added a picture on what the finished product is supposed to look like. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was able to make my code with a rectangle thanks to @3NiGMa, but I need to label it.

Comment: I modified my own code and also added a picture of what it should look like. Is there a way to do it based on that? The labels should be from 0 to 10 (so the first bar is 0, the second is 1, the third is 2, all the way to 10)

Comment: Looking at my code, is there a way to modify the code with that? I made my code into boxes. Please see the picture attached in the problem.

Comment: yep, i just added lines 31-40 into your code, see my answer for the modified version

Comment: Thank you so much!